# Android get image from gallery into two imageviews

Tags: android, android-imageview, image-gallery

i searched and i found how to can to get image from gallery and show it in image view.this is a my source

```
public class CredoUploadFile extends Activity {

private EditText credouploadfileuserid, credouploadfileusername,
        credouploadfileusersurname;

private int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private int choosebutton;
private RoundedImageView credouploadcenter1left,credouploadcenter1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_credo_upload_file);

    credouploadcenter1 = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.credouploadcenter1);

    credouploadcenter1left = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.credouploadcenter1left);
    credouploadcenter1left.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            choosebutton=1;

        }
    });

    credouploadcenter1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            choosebutton=2;

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        if(choosebutton==1)
            credouploadcenter1left.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(picturePath));
         if(choosebutton==2)
            credouploadcenter1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

}
i can to show image from gallery in image view,but i have two imageviews and when i click second imageview and choose some image result is first image view.i can't to show image only imageview witch i clicked.
how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me

Answer (score 0):

In `onActivityResult` you use the same variable  `credouploadcenter1left` for both `if`...

Try:

```
if(choosebutton==1)
   credouploadcenter1left.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
if(choosebutton==2)
   credouploadcenter1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory .decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(choosebutton==1)
    credouploadcenter1left.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
 if(choosebutton==2)
    credouploadcenter1left.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Here is the error, independently of your choose, you will set image always on `credouploadcenter1left`.
You have to set it on `centeruploadcenter1` when you choose second button.